# What Java table components exist?

Tags: java, jtable

In the world of Delphi, there are several very good table components, each with interesting features and a individual look and feel. Now i switched to Java development and JTable feels very "basic" to me.

Are there any feature-rich free or commercial table components available for Java?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JIDE Software provides [JIDE Grids](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/grids.htm), set of extensions for JTable like a tree-table, cell-spanning, sorting and filtering.

I haven't used this product, but I have used their docking framework, which was of decent quality.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a lot of variants of the JTable in [oracle's swing tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Answer (score 1):

Tables with other functionality have already been addressed by others.  Just thought I'd point out that 'Look and Feel' is generally covered by Java PLAFs (Pluggable Look'n'Feel).